# Are there any way to programmatically execute a query with Include Actual Execution Plan and see whether any index suggestion or not

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-performance

I have a quite good number of queries and i want to test each of them with Include Actual Execution Plan feature on sql server management studio

However it is not possible for me to do this manually for 1m + queries

So i wonder can i execute them programmatically (from c#) with Include Actual Execution Plan feature and see whether SQL server suggests any index or not

[image]

Comment: SQL Server has dynamic management views that track missing index stats since SQL 2005: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx

Comment: For the duplicate, the accepted answer `Method 2` is exactly what you are asking for. The "Actual Execution Plan" option is just doing `SET STATISTICS XML ON ` on your query then formatting it for display. You could even save the resultset to a file then open it in Sql Management Studio and it would give you the nice GUI version.

Comment: EDIT: I removed my duplicate because you also ask about getting about the missing index info which the duplicate does not cover. [Link to the original marked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain so how can i execute each one of the queries from C# and save the ones that tells me missing index ?

Comment: I am writing up an answer now to cover that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ty waiting it. that would be really useful. so i can execute each one of the queries on SQL server and save the ones that have missing index :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, before I go in to how to get the Actual Execution Plan in code and find the ones that report needing indexes I would recommend you look in to using the [Database Engine Tuning Adviser (DTA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx), you can feed it a list of all the queries and it will process them telling you possible indexes, statistics, and many other things that can help out planning your queries.

Even better than giving it a list of 1m+ queries is you can get a trace from the server with the actual queries that are being run and it will focus on the queries that are taking up the most time.

---

To answer your original question you will need to add `SET STATISTICS XML ON` at the start of the connection, this will give you the XML data that the GUI you showed is based off of. ([See here for more info about getting the plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)). Once you do that your queries will return with a extra result set containing the xml for the plan in the first row of the first column.

Here is a quick and dirty function that does that.

```
private static string GetXmlPlanForQuery(string queryText)
{
    string result = null;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;

        //Enable the statistics.
        command.CommandText = "SET STATISTICS XML ON";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Run through the query, keeping the first row first column of the last result set.
        command.CommandText = queryText;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            object lastValue = null;
            do
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    lastValue = reader.GetValue(0);
                }
            } while (reader.NextResult());

            if (lastValue != null)
            {
                result = lastValue as string;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here is the XML it returned for the query `select TOTAL_SALES from clients where ACTIVE = 0;` that I ran that I had on one of my local databases.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.5058.0">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementText="SELECT [TOTAL_SALES] FROM [clients] WHERE [ACTIVE]=@1" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SELECT" RetrievedFromCache="false" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0767454" StatementEstRows="315" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" QueryHash="0x708AE72DD31A316" QueryPlanHash="0x214EA79FF76E6771" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound">
          <StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="false" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/>
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="192">
            <MissingIndexes>
              <MissingIndexGroup Impact="94.0522">
                <MissingIndex Database="[exampleDb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CLIENTS]">
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
                    <Column Name="[ACTIVE]" ColumnId="15"/>
                  </ColumnGroup>
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
                    <Column Name="[TOTAL_SALES]" ColumnId="18"/>
                  </ColumnGroup>
                </MissingIndex>
              </MissingIndexGroup>
            </MissingIndexes>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0"/>
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="830838" EstimatedPagesCached="207709" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2"/>
            <RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="315" EstimateIO="0.0749769" EstimateCPU="0.0017685" AvgRowSize="16" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0767454" TableCardinality="1465" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[exampleDb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CLIENTS]" Column="TOTAL_SALES"/>
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="315" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1"/>
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[exampleDb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CLIENTS]" Column="TOTAL_SALES"/>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[exampleDb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CLIENTS]" Index="[imp_clpk_CLIENTS]" IndexKind="Clustered"/>
                <Predicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[exampleDb].[dbo].[CLIENTS].[ACTIVE]=(0)">
                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[exampleDb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CLIENTS]" Column="ACTIVE"/>
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Const ConstValue="(0)"/>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(0)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(0)"/>
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Now, because Microsoft is quite nice, if you [navigate to the namespace listed in the XML](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/) you can actually get a copy of the `.xsd` for the format. You can then from the developer's command prompt do `xsd showplanxml.xsd /classes` and it will give you a `showplanxml.cs` that you can use with the `XmlSerializer`.

Here is a small example program that does a debugger break on a missing index.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = GetXmlPlanForQuery("select TOTAL_SALES from clients where ACTIVE = 0;");
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ShowPlanXML));
    var plan = (ShowPlanXML)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(result));

    var missingIndexes =
        plan.BatchSequence.SelectMany(x => x)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
            .OfType<StmtSimpleType>()
            .Select(x => x.QueryPlan)
            .Where(x => x.MissingIndexes != null && x.MissingIndexes.Any());

    foreach (var queryPlan in missingIndexes)
    {
        //This will hit for each statement in the query that was missing a index, check queryPlan.MissingIndexes to see the indexes that are missing.
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I used XmlSerializer and deseralized it to a class but you could just as easily loaded this in to a XDocument then used [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to find all the nodes named `MissingIndex`.

Comment: ty would this answer work for update queries as well ?

Comment: i suppose it would :) let me give this a try :)

Comment: Hello can you please upload showplanxml.cs i don't know how to do it

Comment: i did run your command but it doesn't compose .cs file it prompts to open visual studio

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG In the start menu in the Visual Studio folder you should have a `Developer Command Prompt` from there doing `xsd.exe` try and run a program (instead of giving you a error), once you can run xsd.exe run it on the download `showplanxml.xsd` like I showed in the answer. If you are getting a prompt to open visual studio you are not running it in a command prompt, there should be no clicking involved other than the click on the shortcut to open the console.

Comment: yes i made it work ty. currently executing 1m+ queries and checking each missing index as a signature. Here how i compose signature for each missing index : http://pastebin.com/iw4kA0Cp can u check it and let me know

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG the only thing I would be concerned about is if `item3.Column` had more than one column, I would not use a hard coded `0` but instead foreach over the collection. Also I would keep `EQUALITY` and the `INCLUDE` group separate, For example using the XML I posted above the recommendation would have been `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <...> ON [dbo].[CLIENTS] ([ACTIVE]) INCLUDE ([TOTAL_SALES])`, Equality ones go in the first set of parenthesis, include go in the `INCLUDE`

Comment: However, what I would ***really*** do is not use this method at all and instead write a `.sql` script with all the queries or get a captured trace file that has all the queries then run the `Database Tuning Engine Adviser` on it.

Comment: ty for answer however i couldnt manage to iterate further can you please update your answer to create a signature for each missing index ? Also i am saving a query for each signature to analyze them later at database tuning engine advisor :)

Comment: No, if you are still having problems go create a new question, create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the code you wrote, and ask for further help there explaining what part you are stuck on. Feel free to link back to this question in your new question.

Comment: ty here the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881086/how-to-create-unique-signature-for-each-missing-index-from-sql-server-statistics