# How do I get an estimated execution plan from SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know how to get it using SSMS, but how would I get the execution plan using C# and ADO.NET? (Assume I know how to handle normal queries in C#.)

Comment: Why would you want to do that in C#?

Comment: Mostly for performance testing. I want to setup my code so that the integration tests capture the estimated cost and flags any test that exceeds its budget. I might capture missing indexes as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can use the below query taken from [Are there any way to programmatically execute a query with Include Actual Execution Plan and see whether any index suggestion or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879543/are-there-any-way-to-programmatically-execute-a-query-with-include-actual-execut)

```
command.CommandText = "SET STATISTICS XML ON";
```

Also, you can use [`SHOWPLAN_ALL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx) option and can set it in your stored procedure probably like `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` (Though I have never tested that personally. So just a suggestion)

> When SET SHOWPLAN_ALL is ON, SQL Server returns execution information for each statement without executing it, and Transact-SQL statements are not executed. After this option is set ON, information about all subsequent Transact-SQL statements are returned until the option is set OFF. For example, if a CREATE TABLE statement is executed while SET SHOWPLAN_ALL is ON, SQL Server returns an error message from a subsequent SELECT statement involving that same table, informing users that the specified table does not exist. Therefore, subsequent references to this table fail. When SET SHOWPLAN_ALL is OFF, SQL Server executes the statements without generating a report.

Comment: Looks like `SET SHOWPLAN_XML` is the one to use if you want details and `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL` if you just want a summary.