# how to get an estimated execution plan using c# to include that code in SSIS component

Tags: c#

I'm settting up a new solution in SSIS to get an estimated execution plan which is a component that have in the input a query and as an output the execution plan , and this component will be developped with c#

Comment: So what's the part you're having trouble with?

Comment: What do you mean by "estimated"?  You need to design the database.   I like using a excel workbook to help design the database.  I make each worksheet a table and each column in the sheet a property of the database.  After I design the database then I create the database in in SQL Server.

Comment: At the begining , I didn't found a code to have the execution plan , after that i found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879543/are-there-any-way-to-programmaticially-execute-a-query-with-include-actual-execut which is very helpful , but now I didn't undrestand how to communicate with the database